# Excel MaxVal + 1 not ticking up when document is finished

Tags: excel, vba, max

im currently having an error code 1004 with VBA for excel, I'm not too familiar with the program but I have been able to determine the issue with the code although i definitely do not know how to fix it.

TLDR on what the code is supposed to do;

once the form is filled copy relevant data to a separate workbook

send an email to the relevant party of new entry

save the entry as a PDF

reset the workbook with the ticket number + 1  to mark up

the issue lies within the last step, once the first PDF file was created the workbook will no longer save as the ticker is stuck on Ticket# 1

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Range("H3").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Device Serial Number"
    Range("H3").Select
    If Range("H3").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("M3").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Reference Standard ID"
    Range("M3").Select
    If Range("M3").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("K9").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Atleast One Dimensional Check"
    Range("K9").Select
    If Range("K9").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("Q9").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Visual Check for Damage"
    Range("Q9").Select
    If Range("Q9").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("U9").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Inital for Damage Check"
    Range("U9").Select
    If Range("U9").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("Q10").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Visual Check for Wear"
    Range("Q10").Select
    If Range("Q10").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("U10").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Inital for Wear Check"
    Range("U10").Select
    If Range("U10").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("Q11").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Visual Check for Travel"
    Range("Q11").Select
    If Range("Q11").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("U11").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Inital for Travel Check"
    Range("U11").Select
    If Range("U11").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("Q12").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Visual Check for Zero"
    Range("Q12").Select
    If Range("Q12").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("U12").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Inital for Zero Check"
    Range("U12").Select
    If Range("U12").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("Q13").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Visual Check for Repeatability"
    Range("Q13").Select
    If Range("Q13").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("U13").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please Enter Inital for Repeatability Check 3x"
    Range("U13").Select
    If Range("U13").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Range("C23").Value = "True" Then MsgBox "Please Check Final Verification Pass or Fail"
    If Range("C23").Value = "True" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open "\\192.168.150.31\Quality Control\Calibration\Periodic Verification\VerificationData(DONOTDELETE).xlsx"
    Application.Run (["GetMax"])
    Application.Run (["SavePrintEmail"])
    Application.Run (["CopyClear"])
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Private Sub GetMax()
Dim WorkRange As Range
Dim MaxVal As Double
Workbooks("VerificationData(DONOTDELETE).xlsx").Activate
Set WorkRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("AK:AK")
MaxVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(WorkRange)
Workbooks("PIV-001.xlsm").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PIV-001").Unprotect ("Moldamatic")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PIV-001").Range("U21").Value = MaxVal + 1
End Sub
Private Sub SavePrintEmail()

    ThisWorkbook.Save
    
  If Len(Dir("\\192.168.150.31\Quality Control\Calibration\Periodic Verification\" & Year(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "\\192.168.150.31\Quality Control\Calibration\Periodic Verification\" & Year(Date)
        End If
          
     
 
Sheets("PIV-001").Select
   

    Sheets("PIV-001").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "\\192.168.150.31\Quality Control\Calibration\Periodic Verification\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Range("U21").Value & "-" & Year(Date), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
    
  
 

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.createitem(0)



On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "Spage@moldamatic.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "NEW INSTRUMENT VERFICATION (TICKET# " & Range("U21").Value & " INSTRUMENT ID# " & Range("H3").Value & " RESULT: " & Range("H22").Value & ")"
    .HTMLBody = "An instrument has just been verfied, please see attached verification report. Verficiation results:  " & Range("H22").Value & " "
    .Attachments.Add "\\192.168.150.31\Quality Control\Calibration\Periodic Verification\" & Year(Date) & "\" & Range("U21").Value & "-" & Year(Date) & ".pdf"
    .send
    End With



On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True

    ThisWorkbook.Save
    
    End Sub
Private Sub CopyClear()
    'Change path to database in line below
    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet

    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim oCol As Long

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCopy As String
    Dim myCell As Range
   
    
    'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
    myCopy = "U21,C22,E22,H3,M3,B9,F9,I9,K9,B10,F10,I10,K10,B11,F11,I11,K11,B12,F12,I12,K12,B13,F13,I13,K13,Q9,U9,Q10,U10,Q11,U11,Q12,U12,Q13,U13,G17"

    Set inputWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PIV-001")
    Workbooks("VerificationData(DONOTDELETE).xlsx").Activate
    Set historyWks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    With historyWks
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

    With inputWks
        Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)
    End With
    
    With historyWks
    With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        End With
        .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
        oCol = 3
        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
            oCol = oCol + 1
        Next myCell
    End With
    Workbooks("PIV-001.xlsm").Activate
    Range("H3,M3,B9,F9,K9,B10,F10,K10,B11,F11,K11,B12,F12,K12,B13,F13,K13,Q9,U9,Q10,U10,Q11,U11,Q12,U12,Q13,U13,G17").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Value = False
    Range("H3:L3").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PIV-001").Protect ("Moldamatic")
    Workbooks("PIV-001.xlsm").Save
    Workbooks("VerificationData(DONOTDELETE).xlsx").Activate
    Workbooks("VerificationData(DONOTDELETE).xlsx").Save
    Workbooks("VerificationData(DONOTDELETE).xlsx").Close
End Sub
```

Comment: The value of `WorksheetFunction.Max(WorkRange)` won't change unless some process updates that range in between reads...

Comment: ...do you have some other code which updates values in that column (AK) ?

Comment: it doesnt seem like there is any other code that updates the value in column (AK)

Comment: updated code to add more context

Answer (score 0):

the issue laid within the MaxVal string, changed the code to get rid of it

new code

```
Private Sub GetMax()
Dim WorkRange As Range
Workbooks("VerificationData(DONOTDELETE).xlsx").Activate
Set WorkRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("AK:AK")
Workbooks("PIV-001.xlsm").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PIV-001").Unprotect ("Moldamatic")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PIV-001").Range("U21").Value = 
Range("U21").Value + 1
End Sub
```